# Javascript error on push function LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, array, push

I am getting below error: when I am trying to use push (function) to add array in another array.

[image]

Javascript code :

```
export default class CarDisplay extends LightningElement {
   @track carvalue; 
    @wire(listCard)
    cartypewire({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.carvalue={value:'',label:'Select Car'};
            console.log('data',data);
            data.forEach(element => {
            const cartype={};
            cartype.label =element.Name;
            cartype.value =element.Id;
            console.log('element',element);
            console.log('element.name',element.Name);
            console.log('element.id',element.Id);
            console.log('cartype',cartype);
          this.carvalue.push(cartype);//getting error  
            console.log('carvalue',this.carvalue);
           });
        }else if(error){  console.log('error',error);
    this.showToast('ERROR',error.body.message,'error');}
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this  `this.carvalue={value:'',label:'Select Car'};` to `this.carvalue=[{value:'',label:'Select Car'}];`

In javascript `push` is available only in array. When you define `{}` it becomes an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.carvalue={value:'',label:'Select'}
```

carvalue is an object not an array